# How to restrict user sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app but I collect funds from my clients manually. How can I restrict user sign up to only those users? Should I create a list of email addresses that the new user needs to belong to? Or is there a better way?

Comment: are you using Devise?

Comment: how about doing an inception? signup within a login or something. Else you can have an authentication key in your Users model which is sent via email to your clients, and have your client paste the authentication key which you have generated prior to their sign up?

Comment: No I'm not using Devise

Answer (score 1):

you can take this approach, instead of using passwords to login you can send them tokens, so they will only log in with the token you send them.

you can create a token generator very easily, assign it to a user in your database and use the actionmailer to send those mails.

The other approach would be to add a boolean column to the users table if it is not checked then they can't login.

Hopes this helps..

Comment: `SecureRandom.hex` is good for a quick token. In addition, the token doesn't need to *replace* user login, it could instead be a required field during sign-up (and populated from the query string when landing on the registration page, so you can send out links to register including a new token, as part of order confirmation)